# Android - String to Time?

Tags: java, android

I have a string ..>> `String x="06:30";`

**how to change this string value to time ?**

**and how to compare this with current time and see which is smaller?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the time is always in that format, you don't need to convert to time. Instead, format the current time in the same format, and simply compare the strings.

Since you tagged `android`, I'll assume you don't have Java 8:

```
String now = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
if (x.compareTo(now) < 0) {
    // x is before now
}
```

If you do have Java 8, or the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) backport, you can parse the time like this:

```
LocalTime xTime = LocalTime.parse(x, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
if (xTime.isBefore(LocalTime.now())) {
    // xTime is before now
}
```

Comment: what if the string value is alwayes a 12h  format how to change it to 24h format because comparing 12h is not working properly

Comment: Can't be 12-hour scale without AM/PM suffix, otherwise how would you compare `06:30` against current time of `3:58 PM` (PDT)? Is that 6:30 in the morning or in the evening?

Comment: I understand now tyvm your answers helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Joda time library:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime time = fmt.parseLocalTime(x);
LocalTime now = new LocalTime();
if (now.before(time)) { /* now is before time */ }
```

Beware of timezone data and settings for both timestamps though. Above example is assuming local time with default timezone setting.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Answer (score 0):

Johan Thomsen's code is much better, please ignore this.

First of all, I'm going to assume your sting is in the format Hour:minute.

```
import java.util.Calendar

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int currentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int currentMinute = c.get(Calendar.Minute);
String s = "06:30";
int hour = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2));
int minute = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3,5));
```

It should be easy to write code comparing these values. You can do this by either comparing the hours and then the minutes, or by combining both into a single totalMinutes and then comparing that. For instance:

```
int totalMinutes = (60*hour)+minute;
int totalCurrentMinutes = (60*currentHour)+currentMinute;
return totalMinutes > totalCurrentMinutes; //this will return True if the time you are testing for is greater than the current time.
```

Comment: Saying it should be easy to compare, when question is about how to compare, so not entirely helpful. Especially since comparing two values (hour and minute) has been known to be done wrong by new(er) programmers.

Comment: That's true, I just fixed that. Thanks

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Comment: Ah thanks, I haven't coded Android apps for a while now. That's good to know